# Finding an angle on a triangle inscribed in a circle

Tags: geometry, circles

**EDIT**: It appears as though the text has made a typo. The angle should be $\theta - \phi$. !!

How is angle $\angle OBW_2$ calculated in terms of $\theta$ or $\phi$ if the only angle measures given are $\phi$ , $90 - \theta$ , and $2\theta$.

The solution shows angle $\angle OBW_2$ as equal to $\theta$. How?

Figure:

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the relation between your two graphics? They are not the same. Are you asking about $\angle OBW_2$ (your first reference) or $\angle OBW_1$ (your second reference)? What is the definition of point $W_2$ in the second graphic? The answer to your question may be that $W_2$ is *defined* so that $\angle OBW_2$ is $\theta$.

Comment: I edited my question. The second graphic is from the solution sheet. $\angle OBW_2$ was not defined in the problem. The reason I need to find $\angle OBW_2$ is because it is used to solve for the Tension force.

Comment: Your "clarification" is still not clear. Your two references to angles are still different. I do not see any $\alpha$ in either graphic. Et cetera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be some mistakes in your supplied drawing.

[image]

Draw the red line through the center O parallel to $BW_2$. (I think the arrow lines are vertical.) Then, $\theta = x$ and $y = 2\theta – x = \theta$. In that case, the red line should be perpendicular to chord AB. If this is so, AB has to be horizontal.

Comment: Yes, the text had a typo. This is what threw me off. The angle should actually be $\theta - \phi$.

Comment: @QuaxtonHale Agreed unless there are some other assumptions like $\phi$ is small or O is not the center.